# cygwin64 shows some directories and files have no permissions

Tags: permissions, cygwin, file-permissions

My cygwin64 installation shows that some files and directories have no permissions:

```
d---------+ 1 dean None       0 Oct  3 16:23 eclipse.workspaces
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 dean None       0 Oct  3 15:10 mailer
----------+ 1 dean None 3044991 Oct  4 10:02 devbook.pdf
```

Cygwin itself doesn't respect these settings since I can do

```
ls -l
```

into directories like eclipse.workspaces and see what is there.  I can read and write into the eclipse.workspaces/ directory.  If I do

```
touch eclipse.workspaces/junk
```

I get

```
$ ls -l eclipse.workspaces/
total 0
d---------+ 1 dean None 0 Oct  3 16:23 default
-rw-r--r--+ 1 dean None 0 Oct 14 16:51 junk
```

All the files and directories I've created today with cygwin64 seem to have normal permissions.  Somewhere in the past a bunch of directories and files got set to no permissions.

I noticed this problem when a script I ran from this machine created files with no permissions on a linux box.

I've tried [this solution from cygwin forums](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-07/msg00323.html) and it didn't change anything.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? That you can create files on your cygwin-computer? That cygwin has problems with old windows-user-settings? That a cygwin-script creates wrong files permissions on a remote system?

Comment: The problem is that for several days cygwin created files and directories with no permissions, as well as creating backup files remotely with no permissions which caused other failures.  I don't know when it started or when it stopped, or what caused it.